# Unhandled exception at 0x0F828F0E (ucrtbased.dll) in Hello World.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000002

Tags: c++, stdio

I am new in C++ and I've started to learn last night

I need help with the following error:

**Unhandled exception at 0x0F828F0E (ucrtbased.dll) in Hello World.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000002.**

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "CUMPARATURI" << endl;

    int mere = 3 + 1;
    int banane = 16 / 4;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Avem " << mere << " mere" << endl;
    cout << "Avem " << banane << " banane" << endl;

    int a = 16, b = 18;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Valoarea lui a este " << a << endl;
    cout << "Dati o valoarea noua lui a : "; cin >> a;
    cout << "Noua valoarea a lui a este : " << a << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Acesta este primul rand \nAcesta este al 2-lea \nAcesta este al 3-lea";
    cout << endl;

    printf("\nAceasta este valoarea lui a: %d ", a);
    printf("\nLocatia lui a este %d \nDa-i valoare noua lui a : ", &a);
    scanf_s("%d", a);
    printf("Noua valoare a lui a este : %d",a);

    _getche();
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: scanf_s("%d", a); scanf needs an int*, not an int

Comment: `printf("\nLocatia lui a este %d \nDa-i valoare noua lui a : ", &a);` is UB as `&a` is not an `int`.

Comment: @NathanOliver seems unlikely that that's actually the problem, though.  nasal demons and all.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yG1OZ69H_-o

Comment: @xaxxon Pretty sure it's not the cause of the current issue but it is still a problem and should be fixed.

Comment: Please turn on and read your compiler's warnings. Would have enabled you to find the issue without bothering to post a question here.

Comment: As @xaxxon said, scanf_s("%d", &a) solves your issue. A debugger is able to solve your issue too.

Comment: Try to use: scanf_s("%d", &a, sizeof(a));

Comment: Use cin, not scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`scanf_s` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), you'll see that the variables you want to read data into are written after a `&`. The `&` takes the *address* of the variable, in fact `scanf_s` needs to know where to write the result in memory.

So, you should fix your code like this:

```
// Note '&a' instead of 'a'
scanf_s("%d", &a);
```

That said, in C++ you may want to consider `std::cin` for reading data into variables, e.g.:

```
int a{};
std::cin >> a;
```

Note that in this case there's no need to use the `&` (*address-of*) operator.